# How do I remove html from SP list text field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, powerbi

I'm doing some reporting in Power BI based off a data connection to a SP list/form that multiple users fill out. One of the fields is a text description field, and I would like to display the text in Power BI. The issue is almost every word of the text is wrapped with HTML tags. I don't think doing text stripping/filtering in the query in PBI Designer is an option here.

Is there a setting in SP Online that I can change to not have this html text wrapped around all the text when I export it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Description field rich text or enhanced rich text?  Changing the text type of the Description field to plain text (if that's an option for you) should resolve the HTML issue.